# Center contents of webpage

Tags: html, css

I want to "centerize" the text and contents of my webpage. Now I don't want to align the text to center, I still want a left alignment but I want significant margins on the left and right so that everything looks relatively center-ish. Can you show me the HTML/CSS to achieve this? THanks.

Answer (score 11):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
   text-align: center; /* Center in IE */
}

#content {
   text-align: left; /* reset text-align for IE */
   margin: 0 auto; /* Center in other browsers */
   width: 800px;
}

html {
   overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; /* Force vertical scrollbar in FF */
}

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">

   content here

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***UPDATE:** I added some CSS that forces a vertical scrollbar in FF as per some comments below.

Comment: It's better to put the text-align: center; on another containing div in case you're using a WYSIWYG editor that will center all your text in the editor.

Comment: +1 because I agree -- I was just giving the simplest example I could for the asker, but in reality I would do exactly as you suggest.

Comment: This works well, but there is a slight problem. I've applied it across all my pages and it seems that for some pages they move slightly to the left/right. This is distracting when my menubar is moving from page to page.

Comment: It seems like the pages with contents/text that can fill the width of the page will have a center that is more "left" than other pages that are almost empty.

Comment: Does it seem like about 30 pixels shift?  Could be because of the scrollbar appearing and disappearing in FF when the content stretches beyond the page.

Comment: Yes, that's what it is! Is there a way of correcting that? In other words set my page to start at a certain number of pixels from the left of the screen (regardless of whether or not there is a scrollbar).

Comment: I updated my answer.  Note that IE always shows the scrollbar's trackbar so there's no shift, so this fix is ONLY for FF, and I only tested it in 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

Create 3 columns on your page.  All your text goes in the center column and can be left alligned.

Have a look here for examples http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
 }

<div id="wrapper">
     <p>This will appear in a centered container</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In some browsers, like IE for example, this will not work. You will have to add another div wrapping #wrapper that sets text-align to center. In #wrapper you should then set text-align to left again.

Comment: I have never experienced that problem? I have used that bit of code on every webpage I have made. With XHTML doctype. If you see: http://dev.korebogen.dk - Its centered in all browsers. And the CSS is only #wrapper { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }

Comment: Alright - maybe it will not center in IE5 - but hell, whos using that anyway? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](http://simplebits.com/notebook/2004/09/08/centering.html) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And in the HTML, wrap everything in:

```
<div id='container'>
...
</div>
```

(Note that this answer differs from meep's in that I'm using `max-width` to give a fluid layout below 800 pixels, whereas he's using `width` to give a fixed layout.)

Comment: ...Except most versions of IE don't know what 'max-width' is.

Comment: IE7 and above do.  For IE6, here's an excellent article on how to achieve the same thing: http://javascript.about.com/library/blwidth.htm

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#div {
  margin:0 auto
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a container div within which you put all your content:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>a sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
         <h1>this is it</h1>
         <p>all content goes here</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then add some css specifying the width and margins of your container div:

```
#container {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```