# Center Large Webpage in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Center contents of webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882344/center-contents-of-webpage)

I have a webpage that is 1640px wide, the main content is centered in the page and is 900px wide. I need to have the webpage center horizontally in the browser window no matter what the users screen or browser size is. Is this possible with javascript, jquery, or css? I dont have any real experience with java so could someone point me in the right direction or do they have a code sample? Thanks for the help!

here is a link to the page to help. [Webpage link](http://test.greatgrizzly.net/contact_us.html)

the problem i might be having is becuase the header and footers are outside on my container and run the entire width of my webpage.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i have tried text-align:center, setting margins to auto, i just can't seem to make the page center in the browser when loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your problem... Your code is doing what you want it to do. You need to remove the css that says `width:1680px;` from your `html,body`

instead make it say: `width:100%;`

hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome! You fixed the problem!!! Everybody thank you so much for all the input and different solutions!

Comment: One quick question if you look at my link again, as a change my screen settings and view the page my header and footer are not showing up when scrolling to the right? any ideas

Comment: I just looked at your `#container` div. You need to make it's width to be 100%. Then you have some inline styling on your `#footer-shadow` div that sets its width to 1040px. You need to set that at 100% as well. Glad I could be of help!

Comment: if that doesnt fix it, then it might have to do with the tables in the footer. Instead of using tables to create columns. You can create divs, giving them a width of 33.33333% OR custom px, and making them float to the left.

Comment: I removed the width from the table and it worked. thanks JCBiggar!

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like this:

```
#container { width: 1640px; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 100%; background-position: center 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a **relative** measurement - i.e 100% percents - and not a fixed number - i.e. 1680px. That way your wrapper will take the entire width of that specific screen no-matter what the resolution is, and the content will be centered:

```
#wrapper {
   width:100%;
}
#content {
width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```